# Partition a very large INNER JOIN SQL query

Tags: mysql, hadoop, join, bigdata, spring-xd

The sql query is fairly standard inner join type.
For example comparing n tables to see which customerId's exist in all n tables would be a basic WHERE ... AND type query.

The problem is the size of the tables are > 10 million records. The database is denormalized. Normalization is not an option.
The query either takes to long to complete or never completes.

I'm not sure if it's relevant but we are using spring xd job modules for other types of queries.

I'm not sure how to partition this sort of job so that it can be run in parallel so that it takes less time and so if a step/subsection fails it can continue from where it left off.

Other posts with similar problem suggest using alternative methods besides the database engine like implementing a LOOP JOIN in code or using MapReduce or Hadoop, having never used either I'm unsure if they are worth looking into for this use case.

What is the standard approach to this sort of operation, I'd expect it to be fairly common. I might be using the wrong search terms to research approaches because I haven't come across any stock standard solutions or clear directions.

The rather cryptic original requirement was:

Compare party_id column in the three very large tables to identify the customer available in three table 
i.e if it is AND operation between three. 
SAMPLE1.PARTY_ID AND SAMPLE2.PARTY_ID AND SAMPLE3.PARTY_ID

If the operation is OR then pick all the customers available in the three tables. 
SAMPLE1.PARTY_ID OR SAMPLE2.PARTY_ID OR SAMPLE3.PARTY_ID

AND / OR are used between tables then performed the comparison as required. SAMPLE1.PARTY_ID AND SAMPLE2.PARTY_ID OR SAMPLE3.PARTY_ID

I set up some 4 test tables each with with this definition

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` (
  `CREATED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PARTY_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `SEQUENCE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SEQUENCE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=978536 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then added 1,000,000 records to each just random numbers in a range that should result in joins.

I used the following test query

```
SELECT `TABLE1`.`PARTY_ID` AS `pi1`, `TABLE2`.`PARTY_ID` AS `pi2`, `TABLE3`.`PARTY_ID` AS `pi3`, `TABLE4`.`PARTY_ID` AS `pi4` FROM `devt1`.`TABLE2` AS `TABLE2`, `devt1`.`TABLE1` AS `TABLE1`, `devt1`.`TABLE3` AS `TABLE3`, `devt1`.`TABLE4` AS `TABLE4` WHERE `TABLE2`.`PARTY_ID` = `TABLE1`.`PARTY_ID` AND `TABLE3`.`PARTY_ID` = `TABLE2`.`PARTY_ID` AND `TABLE4`.`PARTY_ID` = `TABLE3`.`PARTY_ID`
```

It's supposed to complete in under 10 min and for table sizes 10x larger.
My test query still hasn't completed and it has been running for 15 min

Comment: "comparing n tables to see which customerId's exist in all n tables" doesn't sound like a "fairly standard inner join type" to me. It would probably help if you posted an example query of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Doing your own partitioning is a bother, certainly.  If you are hitting this level of processing frequently enough, are you open to moving to a big-data environment?  If so, I suggest http://trustedanalytics.github.io -- I know it can handle the level of join you're trying to do.

Comment: @Uueerdo I added the description of the requirement. It was my original guess that this would be an inner join. But clearly using sql is not the best solution since it takes too long. I'm thinking there might be some alternative algorithm in data science or something

Comment: How long is "too long"? How long does your existing query run? How long do you want it to run? How many tables are you joining? What indexes do they have set up on them? Approximately (orders of magnitude) how many rows do you expect to be returned? Are all the tables > 10 million records, or are some significantly smaller? Will an individual customer have many records on any / some / all of these tables? SQL query optimisation is usually dependant on the specific details of the query to be optimised.

Comment: The DBMS is MySQL. I don't have the query. There are many possible queries with AND/OR combinations. But always matching a single column. This needs to take less then 10min. The objective is to write an spring batch job to insure it's fail safe and efficient. I don't have access to the actual database either, else I'd have a look at how an example query performs. So my question is abstract by necessity not my own design.

Comment: `UNION` queries are your best bet, as demonstrated in the answer from @MarkBannister; if the tables have `party_id` indexed, it would likely be fast even on large tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *may* perform better than the existing join-based query:

```
select party_id from
(select distinct party_id from SAMPLE1 union all
 select distinct party_id from SAMPLE2 union all
 select distinct party_id from SAMPLE3) as ilv
group by party_id 
having count(*) = 3
```

Amend the `count(*)` condition to match the number of tables being queried.

If you want to return `party_id` values that are present in *any* table rather than all, then omit the final `having` clause.

Comment: In the "any table" scenario, the `all` part of `union all` can be omitted as well.

Comment: If  UNION combines row results from one table with rows of another table (vertically) can you explain how this query would exclude any party_id's that don't exist in say SAMPLE2 for example?

Comment: @justify: That's what the `having count(*) = 3` clause does - any `party_id` values that aren't in all 3 tables will have a count of less than three. (This is why the count condition must be amended to match the total number of tables in the query.)

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Ok that does work much much faster! Since this can only work for all AND or all OR, can you extend your answer with an example of correct use of sub-queries to return list of party_id's in SAMPLE1 AND SAMPLE2 AND SAMPLE3 OR SAMPLE4 AND SAMPLE5 then I can see how to code dynamic query generation for any combination

Comment: Also the results need to include GROUP_ID may be I should write a new question