# Use combination of sql union sub-queries to handle combinations of AND/OR conditions for customer filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bigdata

This is a market segmentation analysis related job which runs fairly often I think a few times a day.

The type of queries, I will explain, need to complete in under 10 min, on up to 5 tables with 10 million records in each table.

I'm an sql noob. I'm implementing this as a spring batch job & need to determine the most efficient sql query techniques to use. So I can code dynamic query generation for any combination of AND/OR conditions.

The objective is to select partyId, groupId based on there presence in a number of tables, these tables are updated too frequently for indexing to be very useful. The tables themselves which are identical are essentially bins created by some existing process. A date range condition is used so that only changes since the last job run are considered by the select. (The date range condition is assumed to help query optimization)

So for my test case I have 5 tables all with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` (
  `UPDATED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `PARTY_ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `SEQUENCE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SEQUENCE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2225551 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

From answers and comments on [Partition a very large INNER JOIN SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620437/partition-a-very-large-inner-join-sql-query)

I've pieced together 2 possible queries one for 'all AND' type conditions and one for 'all OR' type conditions.

```
select PARTY_ID from
(select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE1 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE2 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE3 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE4 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE5 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')) as ilv
group by PARTY_ID 
having count(*) = 5;
```

This works for returning a result set of those partyId's which exist in all tables 1-5. The user will be providing requirements for the conditions in the form of AND/OR conditions so this would equate with a purely AND condition set)

```
select PARTY_ID from
(select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE1 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE2 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE3 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE4 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID from TABLE5 WHERE (UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00')) as ilv
group by PARTY_ID;
```

This works for returning a result set of those partyId's which exist any of tables 1-5. The user will be providing requirements for the conditions in the form of AND/OR conditions so this would equate with a purely OR condition set)

What I need is an example of how a combination of AND/OR conditions would translate into this type of query syntax (since it is a lot faster then a standard join)

For instance correct use of sub-queries to return list of party_id's in say TABLE1 AND TABLE2 AND TABLE3 OR TABLE4 AND TABLE5 then I can see how to code dynamic query generation for any combination.

My other question is would the date range in fact help with efficiency?
Also could I effectively use the date range to partition the query so it could be run in parallel?

The reason I'm not sure about this is I'm guessing the sql engine has to loop through all the rows of each table regardless of the existence of the condition. So partitioning the query might result in more total loops ... does such a line of reasoning make sense?

Comment: Since you're doing UNION, you can remove the DISTINCT keywords. (UNION does already remove all duplicates.)

Comment: If Updated is not indexed, then a complete table scan must be performed for each of the unioned queries. Even if Updated is indexed, your query is written so that an index scan would still have to be performed. There is a way to write the query to generate an index seek, but I have to know first if Updated is or can be indexed. Also, what exactly is the difference between the tables? They are physically identical but the data from one obviously means something different than the data from another...

Comment: @TommCatt: Updated can be indexed I suppose but it would have to be done just before the main query ... not sure if that would help. Due to frequent updates of the tables the index would need to be rebuilt every time. With regards to the data, the results are actually partyId only (the query asks in these (up to 60 tables) which partyId's exist in ... whatever condition set specifying table names), so you are correct the groupId doesn't need to be in there ... The groupId in the query results would hold no meaning with groupId being from any of the partyId group with "group by" clause.

Comment: Can you supply some data, a few sanitized rows from a couple of the tables? And when you say "frequent updates," are these actual Update statements or Insert statements? And how frequent is frequent? It looks like you may have a separate table for each type of row instead of one table with a type designation field. I'm hoping that all your problems will go away with a little careful data modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only ever going to be querying rows from the current day, it makes sense to have an overnight job that sets up a new partition on each table for the current day (and moves the previous day's rows into the main partition for each table). That way, you should only be querying thousands, not millions, of records with each query.

If the date/time range can potentially be from *any* day, then it would make more sense to set up a new index on each table, either on `UPDATED` alone or on a combination of `UPDATED` and `PARTY_ID`. If you have the opportunity, I recommend trying your updated query against both sets of indexes, and seeing how they compare.

One approach to implementing the more complex functionality required might be by summing conditional expressions - for example, in the case where you want `PARTY_ID` in `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` and `TABLE3` *or* `TABLE4` and `TABLE5`:

```
select PARTY_ID from
(select distinct PARTY_ID, 'TABLE1' TABLENAME from TABLE1 
 WHERE UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00'  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID, 'TABLE2' TABLENAME from TABLE2 
 WHERE UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00'  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID, 'TABLE3' TABLENAME from TABLE3 
 WHERE UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00'  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID, 'TABLE4' TABLENAME from TABLE4 
 WHERE UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00'  union all
 select distinct PARTY_ID, 'TABLE5' TABLENAME from TABLE5 
 WHERE UPDATED >= '2015-09-18 14:43:44' AND UPDATED <= '2015-09-18 15:00:00') as ilv
GROUP BY PARTY_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TABLENAME IN ('TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE3') THEN 1 END)=3
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN TABLENAME IN ('TABLE4','TABLE5') THEN 1 END)=2;
```

Note that the numbers in the equality expressions (in the `HAVING` clause) need to match the total number of tables being checked in the `CASE` expression - so the query needs to check whether the SUMmed CASE expression equals **3** when checking that the `PARTY_ID` is in all of the first three tables, and needs to check whether the second expression equals **2** when checking the last two tables.